# btrfs volume in fstab fails to boot with compress-force

Tags: linux, debian, compression, btrfs, fstab

in my fstab, the btrfs volume boots with no problem when the option set is `compress=zstd:15`, however, as soon as i set it to `compress-force=zstd:15`, it fails to boot because of a failed dependency

since it only works after logging in and manually running `mount -o remount,compress-force=zstd:15 /mnt/data` which *does* result in `compress-force`, i tried modifying `/etc/profile` to run the above, however this doesn't seem to run, as findmnt reports `compress=zstd:15` and not `compress-force=zstd:15`

how do i enable compress-force on boot?

running debian bullseye

Comment: "failed dependency"... Which one(s)? What's the error message?

Comment: i thought it was because `btrfs device scan` needed to run before using advanced compression options, however, booting after changing `fstab` worked this time, strangely enough.

normally when i change `fstab` it asks for the root password after the dependency fails to load, and i tried this, and it successfully booted.

it's worth noting that i changed the fstab to use `uuid` instead of `/dev/sdb1` and perhaps this is why

i can't reproduce the error, and it's working fine, now